# Calculate the angle between two 3D vectors for each dimension

Tags: c++, matlab, vector

I know how to calculate the angle between two vectors, like suggested here [Angle between two vectors matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330451/angle-between-two-vectors-matlab) , however, what do I have to do to only get the degree in one dimension. So that I can tell if vector `A` and vector `B` have an angle of for example 30° in the xy-dimension, but in the yz-dimension an angle of 40°.

Now I want to know how can I project a vector at the planes in MATLAB ? 
After this I should be able to calculate the angle the same way it is done in the provided link

Comment: "30° in the x-dimension" I cannot imagine how that can make sense. What could make sense is to calculate the angle after projecting onto the xy plane (or xz / yz plane)

Comment: That's more a geometry question than about programming. Two vectors in 3D space share a plane (or not). The angle between them is projected at that plane.

Comment: @tobi303 sry, that's what I meant.

Comment: @user0042 sry is there a SO for this ?

Comment: if thats what you meant, then its trivial: Project onto the plane and then calculate the angle in 2d

Comment: @Kev1n91 SE Math maybe?

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I wanted to know. Could not find this simple answer

Answer (score 3):

While I really really think that its likely you are making some mistake in your maths, prior to this, the solution to your problem is easy.

Projecting the vectors to a Cartesian plane is simple removing that coordinate that doesn belong. E.g. projecting 2 vectors to XY plane, is essentially making their "z" to be equal to zero.